# Simple CMS (PHP/Python)

Tags: php, django, wordpress, content-management-system

I am looking for an easy-to-use [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) that can be used to host a multilingual website with photo galleries and a few forms.

I am open to PHP/Python, excluding [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress)/[Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla)/[Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal).

Comment: It might be helpful to know why you won't consider wordpress/joomla/drupal...

Comment: Further, if you're looking to use a CMS to host a multi-lingual I'm afraid the "lightweight / simple" solutions tend to fail miserably.

Comment: please add the multi-lingual to your question name, it's a hard requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Django CMS 2.0 is a great multilingual CMS.

Views are cached and being a pluggable Django app makes it very extensible.

You would like the plugin approach of the design, is very helpful to integrate existing apps to a project.

http://github.com/digi604/django-cms-2.0/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Try [CMS From Scratch](http://cmsfromscratch.com/). It's hard to get any simpler or easier.

Also, don't forget http://www.opensourcecms.com/.  They host demo versions of most CMSs out there that you can try.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to Ruby, see [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/):  "Radiant is a no-fluff, open source content management system designed for small teams."  Also [Mephisto](http://mephistoblog.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the lighter CMS systems out there don't usually offer a lot - which is why WordPress/Joomla/Drupal have made it so big. WordPress actually takes 9 MB to load the index page on a vanilla install.

Have you looked at http://chryp.net?

If you know how to program in Python or PHP then there are MANY CMSes built by the users of frameworks that offer a lot if you don't mind messing with code.

Answer (score 0):

One of your tags is 'django'.

I don't know if I would call Django simple, but it is easy 
to use - once you know how... It has a very steep learning 
curve.

Perhaps you are really looking for which framework to learn 
and use for web-development for the next many years? I that 
case I would recommend Django. Others systems I considered 
were (all PHP based):

```
Joomla
CMSMS (CMS Made Simple)
Drupal
CodeIgniter,
CakePHP
Symfony
Smarty
Concrete5.
```

I have completed [a Django project](http://msquant.alwaysdata.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you tag `django`, I can suggest you a reusable Django application called [django-photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/). IMHO it's worth it to use a CMS capable framework like Django rather than using a ready made CMS because in the future there would be a chance for you to customize your application. Using a ready made CMS I reckon is not as flexible as using a framework like Django.

Answer (score 0):

For something in Python that isn't Django, you can also try [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [django-blocks](http://code.google.com/p/django-blocks/). Has multi-language Menu, Flatpages and even has a simple Shopping Cart!!